# Novel (1950s or 60s) about a cook on a spaceship to Venus.

Tags: story-identification

The cook, named Chester I think, is a grouch, mainly because he is bitter over a bad knee injury that means he needs a stick for walking. His grumpiness makes him unpopular with many of the ship's company. He is redeemed during a battle on Venus when his actions help his colleagues win. As a reward, the ship's surgeon operates on his leg and he can finally walk unaided down the gangway on return to Earth.

Answer (score 4):

[Operation Springboard](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/21229480-operation-springboard) by John Ball Jr.

> Chester Pawling, keenly interested in space travel, is invited to work
> at a base in the South Pacific where the great scientist, Dr.
> Havensson, is conducting highly secret experiments. That is just the
> beginning of a grand adventure that fulfils Chester’s dream of
> traveling into space. But it is not simple or safe. A rival national
> group has launched a rocket ship and a dangerous space race has begun.
> Chester, who is physically handicapped, gets more than one chance to
> prove that he is as capable as any other member of the crew.
>
> Operation Springboard is a juvenile science fiction novel (published first in 1958 as Operation Space).